# MySQL XDevAPI crashes with "Queue is empty"

Tags: mysql, node.js

I left my development machine on overnight with the `express` server running and when I woke up I noticed the express server had crashed with the following error:

```
C:\Users\James\Projects\nine-tails\server\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\WorkQueue.js:72
        throw new Error('Queue is empty');
        ^

Error: Queue is empty
```

The error is coming from the `xdevapi` module but I can't seem to find anything on queues in the docs or why this error is happening.

Any advice?

**Edit:** Here's the entire log for the error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\James\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start:express' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.0
3 info using node@v10.8.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart:express', 'start:express', 'poststart:express' ]
5 info lifecycle server@1.0.0~prestart:express: server@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle server@1.0.0~start:express: server@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle server@1.0.0~start:express: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle server@1.0.0~start:express: PATH: C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\James\Projects\nine-tails\server\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\James\bin;C:\Python37\Scripts;C:\Python37;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\metasploit-framework\bin;C:\tools\php72;C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
9 verbose lifecycle server@1.0.0~start:express: CWD: C:\Users\James\Projects\nine-tails\server
10 silly lifecycle server@1.0.0~start:express: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development DEBUG=express,database,routes node server.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle server@1.0.0~start:express: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle server@1.0.0~start:express: Failed to exec start:express script
13 verbose stack Error: server@1.0.0 start:express: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development DEBUG=express,database,routes node server.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:249:5)
14 verbose pkgid server@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\James\Projects\nine-tails\server
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\James\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start:express"
18 verbose node v10.8.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error server@1.0.0 start:express: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development DEBUG=express,database,routes node server.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the server@1.0.0 start:express script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

and

```
C:\Users\James\Projects\nine-tails\server\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\WorkQueue.js:72
        throw new Error('Queue is empty');
        ^

Error: Queue is empty
    at WorkQueue.process (C:\Users\James\Projects\nine-tails\server\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\WorkQueue.js:72:15)
    at Client.handleServerMessage (C:\Users\James\Projects\nine-tails\server\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\Protocol\Client.js:201:21)
    at Client.handleNetworkFragment (C:\Users\James\Projects\nine-tails\server\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\Protocol\Client.js:245:14)
    at TLSSocket.stream.on.data (C:\Users\James\Projects\nine-tails\server\node_modules\@mysql\xdevapi\lib\Protocol\Client.js:65:36)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:639:20)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start:express: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development DEBUG=express,database,routes node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start:express script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-05T09_06_40_255Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be happening, unless the X Plugin (MySQL server) is sending some out-of-band or unexpected message (which would be pretty weird).

Anyway, that's not a lot to work with. Maybe you can extend your logging infrastructure (or mess a bit with the response handlers in the connector) too see what's actually happening.

If you find something interesting, I suggest you create a bug report in the official MySQL [issue tracker](https://bugs.mysql.com/) using the `Connector for Node.js` category.

Disclaimer: I'm the project lead dev.

Comment: It would also be interesting if you, @BugHunterUK have any way to reproduce this with your code base. We haven't seen this before. A clearer error wording might be "the server sent something, when we didn't expect." If you can reproduce this we'd be happy to look deeper (probably outside this question) in order to trace it down and fixing it.

Comment: It's happened 3 times in total randomly. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Updated my question with the entire log. Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, the log does not really help that much. If this is indeed a client issue, the work queue is being depleted somehow incorrectly by one of the response handlers. Otherwise it's an X Plugin issue, which would be harder to determine. You would have to do some debugging on your side as well. Maybe you can join the [MySQL Community Slack](https://mysqlcommunity.slack.com) and we can hash out some ideas (this is probably not the best channel to do that).

Comment: Thank you. I will join the Slack.

Comment: Ah I need an oracle email address to join the slack.

Comment: Thanks for joining the slack, sorry we didn't have time at that moment. We're still interested in debugging the issue. A way might be to dump out the `messages` variable, where the error is thrown. (See https://mysqlcommunity.slack.com/archives/C8REVRP96/p1536323377000100 on the MySQL Slack)